# How to get curl left and and reverse effect of that in transitions of UIVIewControllers with C#?

Tags: c#, ios, animation, xamarin

Im searching for tutorials and everything but im not managing to do this.
I found lots of codes in objective C but i cant understand a thing.

I ended up doing my animations like this:

```
 this.NavigationController.PushViewController(new vinhoDescricaoP (glovalVars.vinhosDetList[glovalVars.listNum-1].ID_VINHO),true);
 UIView.BeginAnimations(null);
 UIView.SetAnimationDuration(0.4);
 UIView.SetAnimationTransition(UIViewAnimationTransition.CurlUp, NavigationController.View,true);
 UIView.CommitAnimations();
```

But there is no CurlLeft and Reverse CurlLeft... Please i just need a way to make this animation happens horizontal in normal way and reverse.

Some of these objective C answers told me about using PageViewController so i can like turn it i dont know.

Thanks

Comment: Which programming language are you targeting?

Comment: If answer had helped you, then please accept it so that it may help others in future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to create a paged controller then here is one way to do it:

```
public class ViewC1 : UIViewController
{
    private int index;

    public ViewC1(int i)
    {
        this.index = i;
    }

    public override void ViewDidLoad ()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad ();
        var button = new UIButton (this.View.Bounds);
        button.SetTitle (string.Format ("Controller {0}", index), UIControlState.Normal);
        this.View.AddSubview (button);
    }
}

public class PageViewController : UIPageViewController
{
    public PageViewController ()
    {
        this.DataSource = new DataSource ();
        this.SetViewControllers (new UIViewController[]{ new ViewC1 (0) }, UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection.Forward,
            true, null);
    }
}

internal class DataSource : UIPageViewControllerDataSource
{
    private int index;

    private Func<UIViewController>[] viewControllers = new Func<UIViewController>[]
    {
        ()=> new ViewC1 (0),
        ()=> new ViewC1 (1),
        ()=> new ViewC1 (2),
        ()=> new ViewC1 (3),
        ()=> new ViewC1 (4)
    };

    #region implemented abstract members of UIPageViewControllerDataSource

    public override UIViewController GetPreviousViewController (UIPageViewController pageViewController, UIViewController referenceViewController)
    {
        index = --index < 0 ? viewControllers.Length - 1 : index;
        return viewControllers [index].Invoke();
    }

    public override UIViewController GetNextViewController (UIPageViewController pageViewController, UIViewController referenceViewController)
    {
        index = ++index >= viewControllers.Length ? 0 : index;
        return viewControllers [index].Invoke();
    }

    #endregion
}
```